# SUM in Excel references other sheet when no rows are generated

Tags: excel, java-8, jxls

I am using JXLS library for Excel file creation. As a part of an Excel, I have a simple table containing two columns, that are dynamically generated by JXLS.

```
| ID           | Value           |
| ${record.id} | ${record.value} |
|              | SUM(D10:D10)    |
```

with rows being automatically generated using the XLS command:

```
jx:each(items="export.rows" var="record" lastCell="D10")
```

I am generating a multi-sheet template, where some of the exports might have items in `rows` and other do not. The problem is, for some reason the items which contain empty `rows` change the formula to reference the first sheet which does actually contain some `rows`, effectively changing to formula e.g. to:

```
SUM('SHEET_WITH_ROWS'!D10:'SHEET_WITH_ROWS'!D10)
```

If I export only a single item without `rows`, for the single present sheet the formula gets correctly changed to `=0` and displays nothing.

How can I configure JXLS to not reference the other sheet?

Answer (score 0):

I was unfortunately unable to find a working solution using the JXLS mechanisms. I tried combining JXLS conditions with JXLS each but nothing seemed to work. When the JXLS condition successfully hid the problematic section, a similar problem appeared in another section which originally referenced the sum in the `D11` cell.

I have decided to fix this issue by using a hacky solution, pre-populating the collection with a single element acting as a placeholder:

```
if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(data.getRows())) {
    data.setRows(Collections.singletonList(ExportRow.createEmptyPlaceholder()));
}
```

The empty placeholder is an object with all properties set to `null`, whose output gets ignored by JXLS, forcing the `each` to effectively generate exactly one row which contains nothing.

This seemed like a reasonable tradeoff in my case.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a bug in Jxls formulas calculation.

I recommend you to try to run your code with the latest [Jxls master branch](https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls/src/master/) (you would need to build the binaries with `mvn install`) as several bugs related to formulas calculation were fixed since 2.6.0.

If it still does not work you may raise a bug in [Jxls issue tracker](https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls/issues)